# How to change SVG coordinate origin

Tags: html, web, svg, frontend

I have an SVG element and I am rendering child circle elements with given x, y pixel values/coordinates.
The children are rendered relative to the default origin which is the top left corner of the parent SVG. Is it possible to change this origin?
In my case, I have pixel values/coordinates based on a center origin with both positive and negative x, y values (see this image https://d20khd7ddkh5ls.cloudfront.net/img13_71.jpg) so it would be very convenient if I could set the origin of the svg rather than having to translate the coordinates.
It's easy enough to set a transform-origin, so how do I set a 'coordinate-origin'?

Thanks

Comment: transform="translate(x, y)" where x and y are whatever numbers make sense for your use case. Or alternatively use a viewBox where x and y are negative.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I don't need to translate the parent svg (the graph). The points on the graph need to be rendered relative to the center of the graph.
I'm already using a viewBox on the parent so it handles scaling, but again, I'm not sure how moving the viewBox helps in this situation?

Comment: for the image example you may try to use a viewBox = "-6 -4 12 8" Using this viewBox the oigin (0,0) would be in the center. However unlike the image the y coords will be upside down. To fix it you may need to flip it using transforms

Comment: Okay I see - so this will set the origin of the viewBox to center, but the origin of the parent svg os still top left (so the parent svg is largely out of view). Any way of setting the origin on the svg itself?

Comment: why don't you think that setting a viewBox sets the origin of the svg itself. Please illustrate your thinking by editing your question to include example markup showing and describe what you want instead.